# What means (_NSCFString *) @"<null>"

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, null

In my app, I fetch some online data, and need to parse it.
Sometimes, there is a value that appears in the Variables View as

```
(_NSCFSTring *) @"<null>"
```

I have been running my code successfully in the Simulator and on a device in iOS9.
I used

```
[myString containsString:@"null"];
```

to act in such situation. It felt bad, but it worked.
Now I'm testing on an older device in iOS7, and that is less forgiving: it crashes on that line.

So, I tried

```
[myString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
```

but that doesn't seem to apply.

So, basically, I'm short on knowledge here, and I hope one of you can explain what this is all about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@"<null>"` is the result of converting `[NSNull null]` to a `NSString`, e.g. using:

```
id value = [NSNull null];
NSString *stringValue = [value description];
```

Note that `stringValue` is a string, therefore condition `[myString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]` will be false.

You have to check for `NSNull` before you convert the value to a `NSString`.

One of the typical solutions is converting `NSNull` to `nil`, e.g. declaring a category method on `NSDictionary`:

```
- (id)betterObjectForKey:(NSString *)key {
   id value = [self objectForKey:key];

   if (value == [NSNull null]) {
      return nil;
   }

   return value;
}
```

and then use `betterObjectForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`. Personally I use variant that checks the type of the value (e.g. `NSNumber` or `NSString`) when parsing server data.

Comment: OK, thanks. That answers my question (indeed, this is json data). What would be watertight condition to use at this stage, should I decide not to check for json null values in the first place?